# How can I deploy next js app on an ubuntu vps

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm working on project. where I have created the rest api with node / express.

I have deployed the rest api on my vps with nginx and pm2.

http://umer.pawnhost.com/

I have created the front-end with next js. I'm not using the api folder of next js.

I am using `.env.local` and `next.config.js`

I have looked at the next js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) but they're saying either deploy on vercel or create a custom server.

I didn't get the custom server part

here's how my folder structure looks like:

```
client (Next JS)
------
  .env.local
  next.config.js
  ...

server (Node / Express)
------
  ...
package.json
.env
.gitignore
```

How can I deploy my next js app on the same vps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a frontend express server that handles routing for your nextjs app.
Create a server.js and add the following

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = 3000;

const dev = process.env.APP_ENV === 'local';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

build and start the server

```
"build": "next build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
```

This will start a server at the configured port